# Как преобразовать относительную ссылку в абсолютную ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anglesharp

Вопрос может и стандартный но точного ответа не нашел.
Задача: распарсить сайт и вытащить ссылки на все страницы сайта.
Сам парсинг выполняется с помощью библиотеки AngleSharp.
Однако он вытягивает ссылки в том виде, в котором они записаны на странице.
Поэтому среди прочего встречаются ссылки вида:

```
"~/folder/file.htm"
```

Как преобразовать такие ссылки - можно найти информацию.
Но встречаются также ссылки вида

```
"../../folder/file.htm"
```

И как превратить такую ссылку в абсолютную - я примеров не нашел.
Собственно вопросы:
а) есть ли в библиотеке AngleSharp стандартные методы, позволяющие  преобразовать относительные ссылки в абсолютные?
б) Есть ли какой-нибудь стандартный метод, позволяющий преобразовать ссылки обоих видов в абсолютные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс AngleSharp.Url

Небольшой пример в linqpad'е:

```
    var parser = new HtmlParser();

    var siteBase = "https://mail.ru/mail/something/etc/";
    var siteBaseUrl = new Url(siteBase);

    // Скачали с siteBase документ, тут заглушка - просто образец полученного Html

    var document = parser.Parse(@"<body>
<div class='product'>
    <a href='/url1.html'><img src='img1.jpg' alt=''></a>
    Hello, world
    <div class='comments-likes'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
    <a href='../../folder/file.htm'>link</a>
</div>
</body>");

    var links = document.QuerySelectorAll("a");
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        var url = link.GetAttribute("href");
        url.Dump();
        var urlFull = new Url(siteBaseUrl, url);
        //urlFull.Dump();
        urlFull.Href.Dump();
    }
```

Вывод:

> ```
> /url1.html
> https://mail.ru/url1.html
> ../../folder/file.htm
> https://mail.ru/mail/folder/file.htm
> ```

PS В System есть также [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А есть различие между  var links = document.QuerySelectorAll("a"); и var links =  document.Links ? В AngleSharp.

Comment: @foxhound Любопытный вопрос, никогда не задумывался и пользовался всегда `QuerySelectorAll`: мне редко нужны только ссылки, я обычно подтягиваю списки или блоки, а все списки мне не нужны. Например, `var menuLinks = document.QuerySelectorAll("ul#navbar li a");`

Comment: А что делают методы     url.Dump();  и    urlFull.Href.Dump();
 ?  Я не могу их найти в классе Uri AngleSharp, а с документацией не очень.

Comment: @foxhound `Dump` это метод расширения для отображения объектов в `linqpad`.