# Как на C# удалить дублирующуюся часть строки?

Tags: c#

Есть два стринга

```
string Mainpath = "http://site.info/pages/list";
string Website = "/pages/list/page.aspx";
```

Как видно окончание первого стринга совпадает с началом второго стринга.

Мне нужно получить URL в виде "http://site.info/pages/list/page.aspx".
Для этого нужно соединить два стринга и удалить повторяющийся фрагмент.
Задача осложняется тем, что повторяющийся фрагмент может быть, а может и не быть.

Опытные сишарповоды, подскажите, пожалуйста, как удобнее удалить повторяющийся фрагмент? Пока из идей только распарсить оба стринга по слэшам и в цикле сравнивать, но наверняка есть решение проще.

Comment: @nick_n_a Вы имеете ввиду метод GetComponents для класса System.Uri? Порыл msdn, но так и не придумал как его прикрутить к этой задаче. Я могу вытащить сайт (http://site.info), но мне может понадобиться http://site.info/pages, если pages не будет во втором стринге.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к советующим разобрать url, а не сличать символы. Пример давал в более раннем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694592/213987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  StringBuilder subp = new StringBuilder();
  string Mainpath = "http://site.info/pages/list";
  string Website = "/pages/list/page.aspx";
  int start = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < Website.Length; ++i)
  { 
    subp.Append(Website[i]);
    if (Mainpath.EndsWith(subp.ToString()))
      start = i;
  }
  string fullpach = Mainpath + Website.Substring(start+1);
```

Возникает вопрос, что нужно при таком случае?

```
string Mainpath = "http://site.info/A/B/A/B";
string Website = "/A/B/A/B/page.aspx";
```

`http://site.info/A/B/A/B/page.aspx` или `http://site.info/A/B/A/B/A/B/page.aspx`?

Comment: Должно получиться `http://site.info/A/B/A/B/page.aspx`. Спасибо за ваш вариант, попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Немного извращений с LINQ:

```
        string Mainpath = "http://site.info/pages/list";
        string Website = "/pages/list/page.aspx";

        var difference =
            Mainpath.Split('/')
                .Select((text, i) => new {text, i})
                .Where(
                    x =>
                        !Website.Split('/')
                            .Select((text, i) => new {text, i})
                            .Any(y => y.text == x.text && y.i == x.i))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.i)
                .Select(x=>x.i)
                .FirstOrDefault();;

        var result = string.Join("/", Mainpath.Split('/').Take(difference).Union(Website.Split('/')));
```

Разделим первую строку, развернем вторую строку, тоже разделим, получим первый отличающийся элемент. Дальше возьмем все элементы до различающегося из первой строки и всё из второй, склеим через слэш.

Comment: С LINQ ещё не работал. Буду разбираться, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
string Mainpath = "http://site.info/pages/list";
string Website = "/pages/list/page.aspx";
```

Короткий вариант:

```
int maxN = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= Mainpath.Length && n <= Website.Length; ++n)
    if (Mainpath.Substring(Mainpath.Length - n) == Website.Substring(0, n))
        maxN = n;
string path = Mainpath + Website.Substring(maxN);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Оптимизированный вариант без создания новых строк, быстрее, но грязноват:

```
int count = Math.Min(Mainpath.Length, Website.Length);
while (count > 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < count; ++i)
        if (Mainpath[Mainpath.Length - count + i] != Website[i])
            break;
    if (i == count) break;
    --count;
}
string path = Mainpath + Website.Substring(count);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Comment: Ваш вариант по сути повторяет вариант решения Дмитрия. Циклы с поиском номера символа. Но вы используете разные решения для поиска номера. Спасибо, посмотрю что мне больше подойдёт.