# Как разобрать url строку определенным образом

Tags: c#, url

Всем здравствуйте, мне нужно разобрать строку адреса https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1?page=1 , но это наверное регулярные выражения,или что то другое может есть, мне нужно, чтобы я мог использовать части строки как переменные, то есть они будут меняться программно. rbranch1 одна переменная, 1 это вторая переменная. Как правильно сделать. заранее спасибо

Comment: Разобрать - используйте `Uri`, в нем есть возможность по сегментам разобрать адрес. Собрать - хм, просто `var url = $"mysite.ru/{param1}/page={param2}";`. Пока не очень понятно для каких целей вам такой разбор...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694592/213987 - используйте Uri

Comment: Попробуйте [HttpUtility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777659/extract-the-video-id-from-youtube-url-in-net/39777772#39777772)

Comment: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Делаю парсер, для опыта, ну и вот сейчас решаю вопрос о том, что  страниц, где есть резюме их много. Т.е.https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1?page=1 первая страница одна категория, далее https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1?page=2 эта же категория, страница вторая, также меняются категории на сайте https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch2?page=1  другая категория первая страница.Все это нужно, чтобы организовать глубину парсинга в соответствующей категории.Может в логике я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Можете использовать [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx), все что нужно там [есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjJ8L.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовал [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx), [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx) и [`.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1?page=3&par2=kek&par3=lol");
    Dictionary<string, string> query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var queryArray = uri.Query.Replace('?', '&').Split('&', '=');
    for (int i = 1; i < queryArray.Length; i += 2)
    {
        query.Add(queryArray[i], queryArray[i + 1]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Категории:");
    for (int i = 1; i < uri.Segments.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {i}: {uri.Segments[i].Replace("/", "")}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nПараметры:");
    foreach (var parameter in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {parameter.Key} = {parameter.Value}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Онлайн: http://rextester.com/DJYP20333

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использование Uri лишнее на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Anamnian ну да, если ссылка правильная, то можно и одной регуляркой обойтись, а если это ссылка имеет ошибки? Придумывать все исключения и их обрабатывать?.. Нет. Программист может это написать, но инженер-программист должен искать оптимальные варианты для решения поставленной задачи. Именно `Uri` снимает с меня ответственность на валидацию ссылки, и, если в далёком будущем, у нас изменится формат ссылок, то мне не придётся лезть в старый проект, чтобы что-то исправлять, исправлять будет Microsoft в апдейте. Всегда нужно стараться использовать стандартные инструменты.

Comment: Однако следующую строку uri не сможет определить `new Uri("google.com");`

Comment: @Anamnian потому что она не валидна.

Comment: Только с точки зрения Uri.

Comment: @Anamnian Нет, только с точки зрения пользователя она и валидна. С ссылкой обязан идти протокол. Браузеры автоматически подставляют протоколы `https://` или сразу же редиректят на `www.google.com`. Просто не стоит забывать, что в `TCP/IP` есть разные протоколы (`https`, `ftp`, `tcp`), которые имеют разные значения и без протокола ссылка не будет валидна.

Comment: @Anamnian а еще в ссылке указывается порт. Если он не указан, то значение по-умолчанию для выбранного протокола подставляет браузер, перед тем как отправить запрос. И это тоже обязательная часть ссылки.